# git not add contents in a subfolder in

Tags: git

I have a project which has a modified package forked from pyo (an audio package for python). The structure is as such:

```
├── Mymodule
│   └── mymodule.py
├── README.md
└── pyo
    ├── COPYING.LESSER.txt
    ├── COPYING.txt
    ├── ChangeLog
    ├── README.md
    ├── build
    ├── doc-sphinx
    ├── embedded
    ├── examples
    ├── externals
    ├── include
    ├── installers
    ├── pyo.py
    ├── pyo.pyc
    ├── pyo64.py
    ├── pyo64.pyc
    ├── pyolib
    ├── scripts
    ├── setup.py
    ├── src
    └── utils
```

I got a complain that pyo was a repository so I did `git rm --cached pyo`, then manually removed `.git` and `.gitignore` in `pyo/`. However, afterward `git ls-files` shows nothing in `pyo/` being pushed.

So my question is how I can add all files in pyo/ to my main repository and also don't treat pyo as a submodule.

Many thanks

J

Comment: "*I did `git rm --cached pyo`*" - why?

Comment: because git recommended me to add it as a submodule with <url> which I didn't want to do. So I assumed git rm --cached pyo will just turned it into a non-submodule.

Comment: Using ```git add .``` in the repo's top level should add everything in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your files to git index by executing following command from your repository root folder :

```
git add .
```

Comment: yes, I did do git add . . at the end i solved it by undoing the git rm. Then add everything back in again,